# Good language for introduction to self-modifying algorithms?

Tags: machine-learning, search-algorithms, artificial-intelligence, computer-games

So I am trying to find a language with which i can write code to build/search through deductive reasoning 'nets', as well as self-modify it's search algorithms based on information learned from these nets.
I also want a language that i can use to write scripts for a 2d game engine, as i would like to build visual models of my projects for a web page(to help my job/school prospects).
So far i am only really familiar with MySQL(been working full time as a backend developer for about 7 months), but I have spent quite a bit of time developing relatively formal models for problem solving that i would like to attempt to put into code.
Any advice/suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic, here. But I'll give you one piece of advice: avoid self-modifying code.

Comment: not sure what the distinction is, but i suppose i'll go to programming stack exchange.  Back on topic, why?  Is it issues with compiling while running, or issues with the complexity that comes with this endeavor, or something else?

Comment: People are superstitios about self-modifying code because once you employ this for solving usual engineering problems, you will often find it to be difficult to trace down the reasons for your program's behavior and that the ability of a program to modify itself can be exploited to gain access / information by people / other programs they not allowed to have. However, if these aren't problematic, then any Lisp or Prolog is a safe bet. Something that speaks to broader audience: Python, JavaScript, Lua.

Comment: This is off-topic here.  Before posting on Stack Overflow or any other Stack Exchange site, please read the help pages on that site carefully, and think about how to rephrase your question.  Asking for advice or suggestions is generally not suitable for the Stack Exchange model; see our [help/dont-ask].  Instead, we want answerable questions.  You'd do better to list all of your requirements and then ask "what language meets these needs?" -- but you should first do some research and show what research you've already done.